# macOS Sierra, Security, and Tex Live Utility

Tags: macos, security

After a fresh install of macOS Sierra, I installed the [macTex](https://tug.org/mactex/) distribution without any GUI programs. After that, I installed the latest release of the [Tex Live Utility](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases/tag/1.26) to update my tex distribution via a nice GUI. However, I cannot start the Tex Live Utility because macOS complains about that the program has not been signed by a verified developer. After I tried opening, there is a button under System -> Security to open the program anyway, but I keep going to see the same error message. This worked with another piece of software but with Tex Live Utility, this approach fails. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: You can also try changing that setting to the least restrictive ("Anywhere"? I can't remember exactly what it says) temporarily, opening the program as normal and then reenabling the setting. After a programs runs for the first time, that setting no longer affects execution of it.

Comment: The least restrictive is "App Store and verified Developers". Before Sierra, there was a third option which was basically "Install what you want". This is not there any more...

Comment: Two possible things to try in the answers to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243687/allow-applications-downloaded-from-anywhere-in-macos-sierra).

Comment: Also see http://tug.org/mactex/sierra.html

Answer (score 2):

They have released a fixed version.  You can update to the newest Tex Live Utility from the command line `tlmgr update --self`