# How to allow non-identified developpers'app

Tags: mac, macos

I'm wondering how to allow non-identified developers' apps since I updated my MacBook Pro to macOS Sierra.

[image]

This option seems to have disappeared.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the unidentified app and choose **open**.

You can completely disable gatekeeper with the command:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the answer but it doesn't work neither. The solution is here : http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245029/190551

Comment: The answer you linked to is the same as the answer I gave you. Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: Thank you Chris. It works. To the people who will read this, you can also re enable it by typing :
    sudo spctl --master-enable