# Installing pgadminIII v1.22.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I just got a new MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) with 10.12 installed and am installing various applications on the machine to get it ready for work.  After downloading the `pgadmin3-1.22.1.dmg` from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.22.1/osx/, I am unable to open the program.

**So far, I have tried the following:**

- I found a description of the Gatekeeper updates made to version 10.12 at https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/15/macos-sierra-gatekeeper-changes/ and then attempted to right-click and select 'open' in order to get pgadminIII to open.  This unfortunately didn't work.  A popup is displayed with the following:

  ```
  "pgadmin3" can't be opnened because it is from an unidentified developer."
  ```
- Using the `open` command from terminal.  Same problem -- popup displays the following:

  ```
  "pgadmin3" can't be opnened because it is from an unidentified developer."
  ```
- Using `sudo open` from terminal.  Error is returned within the terminal and is a bit more verbose:

  ```
  LSOpenURLsWithROle() failed with error -10810 for the file /Volumes/pgAdmin3/pgAdmin3.app
  ```

Google and SE have been fruitless so far.  Grateful for any ideas...

Cheers,
James

Comment: This differs from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243687/allow-applications-downloaded-from-anywhere-in-macos-sierra as the right click solution does not work.

Comment: After looking a bit more asking around, I was pointed at one of the [non-accepted answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243687/allow-applications-downloaded-from-anywhere-in-macos-sierra#answer-253943) in the question referenced in my comment above.  The solution, which is to change the file attributes (specifically the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute) ended up solving the problem permanently and can be used to avoid having to always "right-click and open."