# disallow allow apps downloaded from

Tags: macos

In *Security & Privacy / General / Allow Apps downloaded from:*, how to dis-allow apps again after you have allowed?

I am asking simply because I have installed some software that I would like to stop from having these privileges.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you restrict the applications from running, do you want to be asked again the next time you run them, or something else?

Comment: Well I guess both - if I can restrict the app, then I should be asked again the next time I run the app - that would also verify that the app is restricted.

Comment: The way the question is worded, you are asking to disallow software from being able to download and install software.  This makes no sense.  Please consider revising to make it clear what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

While looking for similar I found this link on here - info about how to reverse 'enable' in Terminal might help?

[Allow applications downloaded from anywhere in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243687/allow-applications-downloaded-from-anywhere-in-macos-sierra)

Specifically this section:

Granted this is a little overkill, but it does the job reliably. It
can be re-enabled immediately after launching the application with

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Comment: That relates to enabling/disabling Gatekeeper globally, not just for a single app…?